# Count not matching- MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT dev_block, 
CASE WHEN problem_type = 'Relating to Cultivation' THEN COUNT(dev_block) ELSE 0 END AS RelatingtoCultivation,
CASE WHEN problem_type = 'Relating to storage' THEN COUNT(dev_block) ELSE 0 END AS Relatingtostorage,
CASE WHEN problem_type = 'Relating to transport' THEN COUNT(dev_block) ELSE 0 END AS Relatingtotransport,
CASE WHEN problem_type = 'Relating to marketing' THEN COUNT(dev_block) ELSE 0 END AS Relatingtomarketing,
CASE WHEN problem_type = 'Others' THEN COUNT(dev_block) ELSE 0 END AS OTHERS,
CASE WHEN problem_type = '' THEN COUNT(dev_block) ELSE 0 END AS NoProblem
FROM (SELECT a.dev_block, b.problem_type FROM hd_survey_head a JOIN hd_survey_horti_problems b ON a.survey_id = b.survey_id
WHERE b.problem_head = 'Major Problems being faced for Fruit Crops' AND district = 'SHIMLA') AS z
GROUP BY dev_block


dev_block       RelatingtoCultivation  Relatingtostorage  Relatingtotransport  Relatingtomarketing  Others  NoProblem  
--------------  ---------------------  -----------------  -------------------  -------------------  ------  -----------
BASANTPUR                           0                  0                    0                19209       0            0
CHAUHARA                        11317                  0                    0                    0       0            0
CHAUPAL                        121086                  0                    0                    0       0            0
JUBBAL KOTKHAI                  94635                  0                    0                    0       0            0
KUPVI                               0                  0                    0                 6491       0            0
MASHOBRA                        23572                  0                    0                    0       0            0
NANKHARI                        28695                  0                    0                    0       0            0
NARKANDA                        41885                  0                    0                    0       0            0
RAMPUR                          67094                  0                    0                    0       0            0
ROHRU                           55563                  0                    0                    0       0            0
THEOG                           51964                  0                    0                    0       0            0
TOTU                            34950                  0                    0                    0       0            0
```

The above query gives me this output which is wrong it counts all in just one column what I am trying to do is count the problems which are in the nested query and display it in the column.

```
dev_block  problem_type             
---------  -------------------------
RAMPUR     Relating to Cultivation  
RAMPUR     Relating to Cultivation  
RAMPUR     Relating to Cultivation  
RAMPUR     Relating to Cultivation  
RAMPUR     Relating to storage      
RAMPUR     Relating to storage      
RAMPUR     Relating to transport    
RAMPUR     Relating to transport    
RAMPUR     Relating to marketing    
RAMPUR     Relating to marketing    
RAMPUR     Relating to marketing
```

The above data is the result of the nested query as you can see that **RAMPUR** Block has problems **Relating to marketing**, **Relating to transport** and **Relating to storage** as well but it counts all in **Relating to Cultivation** in the above query

Comment: ' it counts all in just one column' - Really - Relatingtomarketing column also has values??

Comment: yeah Ik but when I see the nested query there are problems like **Relatingtostorage** and **Relatingtotransport** in every block but the query counts it all in one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be taking aggregates of the `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT
    dev_block, 
    SUM(problem_type = 'Relating to Cultivation') AS RelatingtoCultivation,
    SUM(problem_type = 'Relating to storage')     AS Relatingtostorage,
    SUM(problem_type = 'Relating to transport')   AS Relatingtotransport,
    SUM(problem_type = 'Relating to marketing')   AS Relatingtomarketing,
    SUM(problem_type = 'Others') AS OTHERS,
    SUM(problem_type = '') AS NoProblem
FROM (
    SELECT a.dev_block, b.problem_type
    FROM hd_survey_head a
    INNER JOIN hd_survey_horti_problems b ON a.survey_id = b.survey_id
    WHERE b.problem_head = 'Major Problems being faced for Fruit Crops' AND
          district = 'SHIMLA'
) AS z
GROUP BY dev_block;
```